# Why are checkmarks being added in the wrong cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a view that shows a list of users. The current user is able to click on one of the cells, thus following or unfollowing the user in that cell. For some reason, checkmarks are showing up in cells that should not have the checkmark(meaning the current user is following someone that he really isn't). The images for the users are also incorrect. I imagine the reason for that is related to the checkmark error. What am I doin wrong? PLEASE HELP!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {



    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

    var usernames = [""]
    var userIds = [""]
    var userPics = [String:PFFile]()
    var isFollowing = ["":false]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true


        refresher = UIRefreshControl()

        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
        refresh()


    }

    func refresh (){

        let query = PFUser.query()

        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
            if let users = object {

                self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.userIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.userPics.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for objects in users {
                    if let user = objects as? PFUser {


                            if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                                self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                                self.userIds.append(user.objectId!)

                                if let image = user["profileImage"] {
                                    self.userPics[user.objectId!] = image as? PFFile
                                }



                                let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
                                query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)
                                query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId)!)
                                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
                                    if let object = object {

                                        if object.count > 0 {

                                            self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                        } else {
                                            self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {
                                        print(self.isFollowing)
                                        print(self.userIds)

                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                        self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                                    }
                                })
                            }

                        }


                    }
                }

        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return usernames.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UsersTableViewCell {




        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell

        cell.userLabel.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
        if isFollowing[userIds[indexPath.row]] == true {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }

        cell.userImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
        cell.userImage.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.userImage.frame.height/2

        if userPics[userIds[indexPath.row]] != nil {
            userPics[userIds[indexPath.row]]!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
                if let data = data {
                    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }


        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell: UsersTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! UsersTableViewCell

        if isFollowing[userIds[indexPath.row]] == false {

            isFollowing[userIds[indexPath.row]] = true


            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

            let following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
            following["following"] = userIds[indexPath.row]
            following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

            following.saveInBackground()
        } else {

            isFollowing[userIds[indexPath.row]] = false

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            query.whereKey("following", equalTo: userIds[indexPath.row])
            query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
                if let object = object {
                    for users in object {
                        users.deleteInBackground()
                    }
                }
            })

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: One problem is you only ever set `accessoryType`, you never clear it. Table cells get reused, so if one is currently checked, it will not be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Michael said, you need to clear the checkmark, try with this code instead of your `if`

```
cell.accessoryType = isFollowing[userIds[indexPath.row]] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
```